# Subscript is invalid because list is empty in VF page

Tags: list

I am getting the following error while executing a  method :
**Subscript is invalid because list is empty
Error is in expression '{!wrapperlist[0].pricingList}' in component  in page pricingreportquarterselectable**

```
<apex:repeat value="{!wrapperlist[0].pricingList}" var="mwdata">
                    <td>
                        <div class="table_main" style="width:1200px;">
                            <div class="columnLeft" style="width:15%;">&nbsp;</div>
                            <div class="columnLeft" style="width:15%;background-color:#33CC00;">
                                <apex:outputText value="{0, number, ###,###,###,###.##}" rendered="{!IF((serviceLine  == 'Recruitment'),true,false)}">
                                    <apex:param value="{!IF(quarter2, IF(OR(mwdata.Type__c == 'Cancellation Admin',mwdata.Type__c == 'Cancellation Non-Admin',mwdata.Type__c == 'Cancellation Admin & Non-Admin'),cwAggMap[mwdata.country__c].Recruitment_Ca_Total_Allocation_Price_Q2__c,cwAggMap[mwdata.country__c].RecruitmentTotalAllocationPriceQ2__c),IF(quarter3,IF(OR(mwdata.Type__c == 'Cancellation Admin',mwdata.Type__c == 'Cancellation Non-Admin',mwdata.Type__c == 'Cancellation Admin & Non-Admin'), cwAggMap[mwdata.country__c].Recruitment_Ca_Total_Allocation_Price_Q3__c, cwAggMap[mwdata.country__c].RecruitmentTotalAllocationPriceQ3__c), IF(quarter4, IF(OR(mwdata.Type__c == 'Cancellation Admin',mwdata.Type__c == 'Cancellation Non-Admin',mwdata.Type__c == 'Cancellation Admin & Non-Admin'), cwAggMap[mwdata.country__c].Recruitment_Ca_Total_Allocation_Price_Q4__c, cwAggMap[mwdata.country__c].RecruitmentTotalAllocationPriceQ4__c), IF(quarter1, IF(OR(mwdata.Type__c == 'Cancellation Admin',mwdata.Type__c == 'Cancellation Non-Admin',mwdata.Type__c == 'Cancellation Admin & Non-Admin'), cwAggMap[mwdata.country__c].Recruitment_Ca_Total_Allocation_Price_Q1__c, cwAggMap[mwdata.country__c].RecruitmentTotalAllocationPriceQ1__c), 0))))}"/> 
                                </apex:outputText> **
```

Answer (score 2):

You should check for list size first:

```
<apex:outputpanel rendered="{!AND(wrapperlist.size>0,wrapperlist[0].pricingList.size>0)">
    <apex:repeat value="{!wrapperlist[0].pricingList}" var="mwdata">
      ---- 
      <whatever here />
      ... 
      ...
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:outputpanel>
<apex:outputpanel rendered="{!!AND(wrapperlist.size>0,wrapperlist[0].pricingList.size>0)">
    No Price list available
</apex:outputpanel>
```